# Извлечение из MySQL столбца неодинаковых значений

Tags: mysql

Есть таблица, в ней есть столбец "категория".
Надо: посчитать количество неодинаковых значений в столбце (т.е. количество категорий) и извлечь их названия (категория1, категория2...)
гугл не помог, как это сделать
посчитать, я так понял, можно DISTINCT, а вот как извлечь значения?

Comment: DISTINCT он возвращает без повторов. Т.е. если вы делаете `SELECT DISTINCT category` то в результате не будут повторяться сроки с одинаковым category. Используйте решение @Gorets'а

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SELECT CATEGORY, COUNT(*) FROM TABLE GROUP BY CATEGORY